# Is it a good idea to use datastax mapper to save thousands of records using saveAsync

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, mapper

I need to save thousands of records in minimal possible time and in a reliable way. As I am new to datastax driver I am not aware of the best way to executing BULK writes onto Cassandra

All the records belong to a single parathion (not considering replication here) 
The records count may vary from 250 to 25000

```
public void save(List<CassandraResource> listOfCassandraResource) 
{
    Mapper<CassandraResource> mapper = this.mappingManager.mapper(CassandraResource.class, this.keyspace);
    mapper.setDefaultSaveOptions(Option.saveNullFields(false));
    for (CassandraResource resource: listOfCassandraResource)
    {
        ListenableFuture<Void> future = mapper.saveAsync(resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the asynchronous queries is standard pattern.  You only need to take care that you don't overload your system - driver has limit on number  in-flight requests per connection/host, and it's 1024 by default. You need to increase max number of in-flight requests per connection to some reasonable value (max 32k).

This could be done when you configure `Cluster` object, or in the run-time:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
poolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768);
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().withContactPoints("...")
     .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions).build();
```

See more [driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/) for more details.

If you have much more data, then you may need to use some kind of semaphore, etc. to prevent submission of too many requests.  You can see one of the examples [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/SessionLimiter.java#L16).